# How would I make it so that my background color stays within the confinement of my wrapper and maintain responsivity?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I want to make it so that my red background color is exactly the same height as my wrapper so I don't need to manually put a height value and that way it can be responsive across the board (on desktop and mobile).

I've tried `height: auto;` but that didn't work.  I've also tried to get rid of `position: absolute;` on the `rectangle` class but that didn't work either as well as a ton of other ways :(. How'd I go about rectifying this issue?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0qp9f5m/81/)  for reference.

**HTML and CSS**:

```css
.section-five-wrapper {
   background: rgba(0,31,168,1);
   position: relative;
 }

.rectangle {
    height: 380px;
    width: 129px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-five-wrapper">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You closed the rectangle div too soon

Comment: ...and why are you using a div to create a background?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah I know what you mean, I tried placing the closing `</div>` right after the last `<p>text</p>` but that still didn't work.

Comment: Your fiddle and question code do not match. Also, it's not clear what this is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1):

add height:100% to .rectangle to filled parent div =>

```
.section-five-wrapper {
    background: rgba(0,31,168,1);
  position: relative;
   }

   .rectangle {
   height: 100%;
   width: 129px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
        }
```